# Communication between Selenium and custom web extension

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm using Selenium (python) to automate some tests on websites. Because selenium's API is quite limited, I'm using a web extension to perform advanced javascript tests.

What would be the proper way to communicate results from the webextension back to the python script? So far, I'm passing them trough console.log messages, but it fails if the target site overrides console.log() (and it seems quite hack-y anyway).

Comment: what you mean by advanced js scripts ? Can you provide an example on the scripts you need to run ?

Comment: Among others, I need to override functions, which needs to be done early during page load, and selenium cannot do that (see https://intoli.com/blog/javascript-injection/ )

Comment: Any updates on this @Perdu?! Want to further debug?

Comment: I ended up keeping the console.log() method, since there does not seem to be a non-hacky way to do this anyway

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably tackle this the following way:

***Firstly,*** if you have control over the web extension's source code, then I'd add a simple method which serializes your data into a nice format, then stores it into the browser's [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/storage/local).

**!Note:** If you haven't worked with this, don't worry, there are multiple examples online. You have to keep into consideration that you're also limited to a **5-10 MB** local storage limit for your data (*varying across browsers*).

***Secondly,*** you'd have to read the `localStorage` values. I see two ways to do this:

- make use of your underlying Selenium-based framework's API (*usually all of them have some sort of localStorage/cookies API call*). **For example:** in most frameworks you can use the [.execute()](https://webdriver.io/docs/api/browser/execute.html) command (*or executeScript*) to set the local storage value: `browser.execute('localStorage.setItem('PerduData', <dataObject>);');`
- use plain JavaScript inside your scripts to set the same local storage value

---

I'm sure there are multiple ways to achieve the same outcome. If you're skilled at working with files, you can also consider storing the data object on other browser, or machine (*OS*) storage areas.

***Lastly,*** I think the most elegant way to achieve this is by using some third-party storage which has a publicly exposed API that can ultimately accessed by both ***webextension*** & ***Selenium script***.

Hope this helps!